# Can you tell me what this SQL would do?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I accidentally included the word "data" in a SQL script I wrote and now am not sure what this does.  Can someone tell me what the following script would actually do if the Rollback transaction were not set?

```
Begin Transaction
data
Rollback Transaction
```

I think "Data" is in the future reserved keyword list in our SQl Server.  But I'm not sure if this is why the script runs without error.

```
Begin Transaction
data
Rollback Transaction
```

Not sure what happened.  The script ran correctly

Comment: Is it a full script or just a portion? If it's a portion - does it envoloped in `if`s? Can you copy this 3 lines and run it in separate session?

Answer (score 4):

You are aliasing the transaction as `data`

Without the rollback you would just have an open transaction called `data`

Comment: Something that would be clear to see if SQL Server enforced the semi-colon for statements.

Comment: @EzLo [tssqllinter](https://github.com/tsqllint/tsqllint) exists. And mssql enforce semi-colon but not consistently. Such as `;WITH`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

according to my knowledge and the keywords for SQL Server, disponible here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

there is no meaning for `data` word, but it could be an abbreviation for `database`, or it could just be a bug

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.